# How to programmatically list functions from a module's path?

Tags: python, import

I need to write a script that reads a certain module (not as an import) and yields a list of its function names.

Something like that:

```py
# script_to_be_listed.py

def function1():
    pass

def function2():
    pass
```

Where this:

`python my_reader_script.py script_to_be_listed.py`

Should print this:

```
function1
function2
```

I have already tried using `inspect` and `dir` but it only works if I import the module (which I don't know exactly what will be given).

If there is no native module to help me out on such task, could you guys suggest me a nice way to do so?

OBS: I'm doing this to automatically create some Lambda functions on AWS and naming them as the functions from `script_to_be_listed.py`.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyclbr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @user2357112's comment, you can use the `pyclbr.readmodule_ex` function to read a module, iterate through the items of the returning dict, and print the key if the value is an instance of `pyclbr.Function`:

```
import pyclbr

for name, obj in pyclbr.readmodule_ex('module_to_be_browsed', ['/path/to/script']).items():
    if isinstance(obj, pyclbr.Function):
        print(name)
```

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks for helping me out.